# How do I make a JavaScript form with validation and when submitted it goes nowhere

Tags: javascript, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently trying to learn how to make a JavaScript form with validation and when the button is pressed it just prompts the user that their form is submitted and it doesn't actually send the form anywhere.

Comment: I've tested here and I was redirected to `demo_form.asp`. And why not use the tag `pattern` for validation?

Comment: Attribute `pattern` you mean :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Event.preventDefault()`

You can learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). Calling `preventDefault` during any stage of an event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur.

See [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mL649vk2/) with two input boxes. Notice the `<br>` makes a line break putting each input box on a new line.

```
<script>
function validateForm(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Name must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
   <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
       onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="post">
       Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
       New TextBox: <input type="text" name="textBox"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! would it be possible for you to tell me how to add a second section in the form to fill out and submit with the same button?

Comment: how do you mean? sorry I don't quite follow.

Comment: Sorry I meant how do I add another textbox to the form? quite new at the stuff sorry

Comment: all good, it takes a while to learn but you will get there! see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

The onclick event will parse an event object if you have a parameter for it in the handling function so you could do:

```
function validateForm(evt) {
//.preventDefault is a method of JavaScript events 
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

So basically you can add logic before or after the submit button is pressed doing client side validation and cancel the event of the validation fails, then get mad at the user for being a numpty.